# Extreme lag while typing in ubuntu's terminal or text editor

Tags: command-line, vmware, sublime-text

Okay so, i have a laptop that is dual boot with ubuntu lunar lobster and windows 11. Ubuntu has been working all fine since forever. I was recently using centos on vmware on ubuntu. and all of a sudden the terminal started lagging in both centos and ubuntu. I uninstalled vmware but now the lag is permanent. Every time i open a text editor or sublime text and terminal at the same time, both text editor/sublime and the terminal start lagging a lot. If I type, sometimes the text takes upto 5 to 6 seconds to appear on the screen. I don't know what the problem is or how to fix it, please help. My hardware is all perfect and everything else is working fine as well.

output of inxi -G :

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 44.2 driver: dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1 renderer: Mesa Intel HD
    Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
```

Comment: Depending on your graphics card, you might change the mesa lib. Execute `inxi -G` in a terminal and copy the output (as text) into your question (**not** into the comments)

Comment: @kanehekili done.

Comment: I have an older Intel card - same problems and I installed "mesa-amber" instead of "mesa" - but since I'm not sure it'll help with "iris" so you should check [here](https://docs.mesa3d.org/amber.html) if your card will be supported. I did that on Arch Linux, so I can't give a helpful answer.  But it seems that "Iris" is not affected ...